# CSS Linear Gradient angle

Tags: css, gradient

If I specify 70° in my linear gradient function, does that mean 70° from the y-axis clockwise or 70° from the x-axis counterclockwise/20° from the y-axis clockwise. Both seem to have been supported at some point...

Answer (score 1):

Ok it seems that with modern browsers, 70° means 70° clockwise from the y-axis, while older browsers implementing an older, prefixed specification would interpret this as 20° from the y-axis clockwise.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient), its basis is from the y-axis.

[image]